# Formatting a command in python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subprocess

I was able to run this command through the command line but when I transfer it over to a Python script and run it, it doesn't work.

```
test = 'aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-563b6379 --name "rwong_TestInstance" --output text --description "rwong_TestInstance" --no-reboot > "V:\rwong\Work Files\Python\test.txt"'
subprocess.call(test)
```

I get an error where it says "returned non-zero exit status 255". Is it because of the way I formatted the string? Overall, what are my options to get this to work?

Edit: It has been solved by J.F. Sebastian

Comment: By default `subprocess.call` has `shell=False`. You'll need to call this through a shell, so use `subprocess.call(test, shell=True)`. Btw, dgsleeps answer about the escape characters is correct also.

Comment: I thought about using shell=True but I thought there was some security risk involved with using shell=True

Comment: If you use any user generated parts of the command it is. If you want to call it without a shell, you have to convert the shell command into a list of arguments. For example this `subprocess.call('ls -l', shell=True)` would become `subprocess.call(['ls', '-l'], shell=False)`. You have to do this, because it is the shell that separates the arguments for you, when you use `shell=True`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for providing that clarity on shell=True and I will remember this tip for later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is `aws.exe` somewhere in %PATH% on your Windows machine then to save its output in the given file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

cmd = ('aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-563b6379 '
       '--name rwong_TestInstance --output text '
       '--description rwong_TestInstance --no-reboot')
with open(r"V:\rwong\Work Files\Python\test.txt", 'wb', 0) as file:
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, stdout=file)
```

i.e., there are at least two issues in your code:

1. Escape sequences such as `\r\t` [as pointed out by @dgsleeps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269287/4279)
2. `>` is a shell redirection operator i.e., you either need to run the shell or emulate it in Python

Comment: Wow, that worked out the way I needed to. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Character "\r" is beeing taken as cartridge return and "\t" as tab; use raw imput by adding "r" right before your single quotes; take a look at this:

```
>>> test = 'aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-563b6379 --name "rwong_TestInstance" --output text --description "rwong_TestInstance" --no-reboot > "V:\rwong\Work Files\Python\test.txt"'
>>> len(test)
172
>>> test2 = r'aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-563b6379 --name "rwong_TestInstance" --output text --description "rwong_TestInstance" --no-reboot > "V:\rwong\Work Files\Python\test.txt"'
>>> len(test2)
174
```

Comment: I see, but sadly it is still giving me the same error. In addition to your answer, I also tried adding "\\" to the file path as a escape(?) character but still no change.